# What is the literature implementation of self-organizing lists?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, lists

I'm trying to implement [self-organizing lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_list) DS to publish as a public module. Over the course of Algorithms, we learnt that if you add a new element to the list, it should still do the huriectics. For example, in Move-To-Front, when you do `insert(2)` it will add `2` to the end of the list and then move it to the front right away (without the need to call `find(2)`).

[Looking into different implementation online](https://github.com/Riturajcse/Self-Organizing-List/blob/master/mtfList_test.go), I see that they perform the heretics only when `find()` method is called. When calling `insert()` they don't perform the heretics.

For example:

```
moveToFrontLst = new MoveToFrontLst();
moveToFrontLst.append(1);
moveToFrontLst.append(2);
moveToFrontLst.append(3);
```

Over the course we learnt that `moveToFrontLst` contains `[3,2,1]`, while the implementations online all return `[1,2,3]`.

It was proven that Move to Front algorithm is 2-competitive, is it the first version or the second version? What is the literature implementation of self-organizing lists?